# NotSerializableException on java scanner?

Tags: java

I was having problems solving a notSeriazable all of my class implements seriazable but it always give me an error about it.

```
 java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.Scanner
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at Assign3.main(Assign3.java:119)
```

Scanner is a class right I doesnt make sense.. What I think is that Scanner should be serialized as well?? but I cant touch the Scanner class.

```
Bank b = new Bank(100.0);
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("try.txt"));

        save.writeObject(b);


        save.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Bank implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int Maxtransaction = 1000;
public Transaction[] transactions = new Transaction[Maxtransaction];
private int numTransactions = 0;
private double balance;
Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

public Bank()
{
}

public Bank(double balance)
{
    this.balance = balance;
}

public double getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.print("\nTRANSACTION RECORD:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<numTransactions;i++)
        {
        System.out.print(transactions[i].toString()+"\n"); 
        }
    System.out.print("BALANCE : $"+getBalance()+"\n");

}

public boolean addTransaction(Category categories)
{
    if(numTransactions>Maxtransaction){return false;}
    else{
    String[] chooseaccountletter = {"c","d"};
    String chooseaccount;
    boolean erroraccount = true;

    System.out.print("\n");
    do{
    System.out.print("Enter a c for credit or d for debit: ");
        chooseaccount = sn.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<chooseaccountletter.length;i++)
            {
              if(chooseaccountletter[i].equals(chooseaccount))
              {
                  erroraccount = false;
                  break;
              }
            }
      }while(erroraccount);

    if(chooseaccountletter[0].equals(chooseaccount))
    {
        Transaction credit = new CreditTransaction();
        credit.getTransactionInfo(categories);
        credit.getAmout();
        balance += credit.getAmout();
        transactions[numTransactions] = credit;
    }//end credit

    if(chooseaccountletter[1].equals(chooseaccount))
    {
        Transaction debit = new DebitTransaction();
        debit.getTransactionInfo(categories);
        debit.getAmout();
        balance += debit.getAmout();
        transactions[numTransactions] = debit;
    }//end debit
    numTransactions++;
    return true;
    }

}

public void displayCategory(String Category)
{   
    double total = 0;
    System.out.print("\nTransactions for Category "+Category+" :\n");


    for(int i = 0; i<numTransactions;i++){
        if(transactions[i].getCategory() == Category)
            {
                System.out.print(transactions[i].toString()+"\n");
                total += transactions[i].getAmout(); 
            }
        }

    System.out.print("Category Balance : $"+total+"\n");
}

}
```

Comment: where you are using Scanner Object ?

Comment: Inside the Bank class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) does not implement `Serializable`, so if your `Bank` class contains a `Scanner` object it won't be serializable either.  You'd have to either remove the `Scanner` or mark it as either `transient` or `static` in order for `Bank` objects to be serializable.  (Be aware that marking the scanner as static would make it belong to the class, not individual instances of `Bank`. You're probably better off making it transient.)

Comment: So How can I do it? by putting it in the main class?

Answer (score 1):

Please show what members `Bank` has. If any of its members do not implement `Serializable`, then the class itself cannot be serialized, unless explicitly marked for exclusion with transient.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the `Scanner` object in the Bank class as `transient` to make it serializable, or move the `Scanner` object into methods.